# Differences between the different ways to access and modify elements in a vector

Tags: vector, rust

I defined an enum called `Cell` and an struct named `Universe`:

```
enum Cell {
    Dead,
    Alive,
}

struct Universe {
    width: u64,
    height: u64,
    cells: Vec<Cell>,
}
```

and I defined a method called `randomize`, like this:

```
impl Universe {
    pub fn randomize(&mut self) {
        for cell in self.cells.iter_mut() {
            let cell_is_alive = rand::thread_rng().gen_bool(0.5);
            if cell_is_alive {
                *cell = Cell::Alive;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the method works as I expected. But here is the problem, if I change the method to:

```
impl Universe {
    pub fn randomize(&mut self) {
        for mut cell in self.cells.iter_mut() {
            let cell_is_alive = rand::thread_rng().gen_bool(0.5);
            if cell_is_alive {
                *cell = Cell::Alive;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(`mut` after the `for`)

the code *also* works as well. Then, if I change the code to:

```
impl Universe {
    pub fn randomize(&mut self) {
        for &mut cell in self.cells.iter_mut() {
            let cell_is_alive = rand::thread_rng().gen_bool(0.5);
            if cell_is_alive {
                *cell = &mut Cell::Alive;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the compiler says the following

```
error[E0614]: type `game::Cell` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src\game.rs:28:17
   |
28 |                 *cell = &mut Cell::Alive;
   |                 ^^^^^
```

and the weirdest for me is the following:

```
impl Universe {
    pub fn randomize(&mut self) {
        for mut cell in self.cells.iter_mut() {
            let cell_is_alive = rand::thread_rng().gen_bool(0.5);
            if cell_is_alive {
                cell = &mut Cell::Alive;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The previous one compiles but appears do nothing at all to `cells`.

- What difference made the `mut` after the `for` in the second version?
- Why I can't dereference the `cell` in the third version when I did exactly that (I think) in the first one?
- Why suddenly the last version compiles perfectly but doesn't randomize `cells`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to `let () = cell;` in your code, you can trigger errors with an explicit description of the type of `cell` (this trick helps me a lot when I am lost).

`for cell in self.cells.iter_mut()` declares `cell` as a `&mut Cell`; this is what you want for the following operations, i.e. mutate the `Cell`s that are inside the vector.

`for mut cell in self.cells.iter_mut()` also declares `cell` as a `&mut Cell` but the `mut` keyword you added applies to the **binding**. You can make `cell` point to something else after: `cell = &mut another_Cell;`.
If you know C, this is `Cell *cell;` instead of `Cell * const cell;`, the `const` **after** `*` applies to the pointer **itself** not the pointed-to object (`const` before the `*` applies to the pointed-to object, like the difference between `&mut` and `&`).

`for &mut cell in self.cells.iter_mut()` declares `cell` as a `Cell` because the `&mut cell` part is a pattern matching with what each iteration provides. Since we saw that each iteration provided an `&mut Cell`, matching this with your pattern makes that your `cell` should be a `Cell` (a value, not a reference).
Your `Cell` type is not `Copy` so this operation should **consume** the `Cell` from the vector, but it is impossible since we use the vector through a **borrow**.
Even is we decided to change all the code in order to *consume* the `Universe` and its vector, `*cell = ...` would not be allowed since `cell` would be a value (not a mutable reference).

These three situations out of the context:

- `let r = &mut something;`: `r` points **once for all** to `something` and can mutate it.
- `let mut r = &mut something;`: `r` points to `something`, can mutate it, but can be reassigned later in order to **point to something else** (and mutate it also).
- `if let &mut v = &mut something {`: `v` is a copy of `something` (if allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Rust tries to match patterns, basically.

```
for cell in cells.iter_mut()
```

`cells.iter_mut()` returns a `&mut Cell`, so that's the type given to `cell`. You can't mutate `cell`, only the value it points to.

```
for mut cell in cells.iter_mut()
```

Pattern matching doesn't work here, so `cell` is now just a `mut &mut Cell`. Now you can change the value of `cell`, i.e., make it a mutable pointer to some other `Cell`. You didn't use that in your second example, so it works identically to your 1st case. In your 4th example, you try to assign `&mut Cell::Alive` to `cell`, which is a `mut &mut Cell`. So basically you a creating a new instance of `Cell`, and giving `cell` a mutable pointer to it. You never mutated the actual list of `cells`.

```
for &mut cell in cells.iter_mut()
```

This is where the pattern matching comes into play. The `Iterator` returns an `&mut Cell`, and you're trying to assign it to `&mut cell`, so Rust makes `cell` a `mut Cell` pointing into `cells`, so you can just do `cell = Cell::Alive` without dereferencing.